# Does having one slice managing multiple state/data have any performance impact in react app (redux-toolkit)

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I'm trying to manage multiple states using an object as an initial state and each property of this object representing independent data. Does this have an impact on performance? I'm avoiding using multiple slices and combineRudecers.

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = {
  appraisalsData: [],
  preMonthData: [],
  fullYearData: [],
  PA_Score: [],
  userData: [],
  agentNames: [],
  activeUser: {},
  user:"",
};

export const DataSlice = createSlice({
  name: "AllData",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    updateUser: (state, action) => {
      state.activeUser = action.payload;
      state.user = action.payload.username
    },
    updateData: (state, action) => {
      state.appraisalsData = action.payload
    },
  },
});

// Action creators are generated for each case reducer function
export const { updateData, updateUser } = DataSlice.actions;

export default DataSlice.reducer;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not have an performance impact. Split the data to slices may help for organizing the code and the state structure, but you can avoid it - and it is actually just like ordinary redux code (without redux toolkit).